# How to read the target of a symlink in android using java

Tags: java, android

In Linux, you read the target of a symbolic link using the `readlink` command followed by the path to the symlink. How do you do this in Android using Java? Apparently `java.nio.File.Files.readSymbolicLink(String)` is not available in android, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use File.getCannonicalPath().  This will get the actual path of the file, following any symlinks.

Comment: That'll definitely do it. Thanks